# Rotation of a boat animation in C++

Tags: c++, animation, rotation, 2d, glut

I'm creating an attack boat game in c++ and I have an issue with my boat following the mouse around the screen. My plan is to have the boat follow the mouse more like a boat (slow rotations, instead of instantaneous whilst taking about 4 seconds to do a 360 turn) and for the most part it does what it should.

The bug happens when the mouse is on the left side of the screen (as soon as my mouse crosses the -x axis),  as the boat follows the mouse, the boat turns in the wrong direction and does a 360, instead of following the mouse.

This is the code i'm using to do my boat turning.

```
        angle = atan2(delta_y, delta_x) * 180.0 / PI; 

        //Rotate the boat towards the mouse and
        //make the boat turn more realistically
        if (angle - rotate > 0) {
            rotate += 1.0f; // turns left
        } else if (angle - rotate < 0) {
            rotate -= 1.0f; // turns right
        }
        if (angle - rotate >= 360.0f) {
            rotate = 0.0f;
        }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to clamp the angle difference. It should be on interval `<-pi,+pi> [rad]` so any angle difference outside this interval will lead to such problems. Try this instead:

```
angle = atan2(delta_y, delta_x) * 180.0 / PI;  // target [deg]
da = angle-rotate; // unclamped delta [deg]
while (da<-180.0f) da+=360.0f;
while (da>+180.0f) da-=360.0f;
     if (da >= +1.0f) rotate += 1.0f;
else if (da <= -1.0f) rotate -= 1.0f;
else                  rotate  = 0.0f;
```